# Find single experiment probability of success (Beta?)

Tags: binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

If I made $n$ experiments and $s$ of them where successfull, can I say that the probability of success in a single experiment $p$ is distributed by
$p \sim \mathrm{Beta}(s + 1, (n − s) + 1)$?

If not, how is $p$ distributed?

Answer (score 1):

Your description is incomplete. What is $p$? We can guess that the assumptions you are making is that $p$ is the parameter of binomial distribution, so that

$$ x \sim \mathcal{Bin}(n, p) $$

and you want to estimate it from the observed data. You may take a maximum likelihood estimate of it as $\hat p = x/n$, but what you are showing is the Bayesian beta-binomial model, where you assume that parameter $p$ is a random variable and you assume a uniform beta distribution for it. In such case, the beta distribution you are describing is the *posterior* distribution of $p$. But this is the distribution of $p$ estimated from your data and the prior, not *the* distribution of $p$. To learn more about beta-binomial model see other questions tagged as [beta-binomial](/questions/tagged/beta-binomial).

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it! Just  to make sure: Is this correct? If p∼U(0,1), then (p|x=s)∼Beta(s+1,(n−s)+1) ?

Comment: @HadasBiran yes, if you assume uniform prior for p then this is the posterior.